# dynamic memory array using logic loop

Tags: c++, loops, memory, dynamic

I have a question related to dynamic memory.  I have pretty much given up on using it and use vectors instead now, but would still love to know why the following type of code often gives me a runtime error with bad memory allocation.  Is there a way to do this with dynamic memory?

The idea is basically using a loop to increase the size of an array, based on some condition.  As stated, I now only use vector.push_back() for this, but thought I'd post and see if there were any insights.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    ifstream infile.open("file.txt");

    string str1, str2; stringstream os;

    int length;
    string *vecarr = new string[length];
    length = 0;

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile,str1);
        if(str1.find("expression") != string::npos)
        {
            length++;
            vecarr[length-1] = str1;
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about memory for now. You have  much bigger problem: `eof()`

Answer (score 2):

`length` is uninitialized in the expression `new string[length]`, so this is plain *undefined behaviour*. You must not read an uninitialized `int` variable.

Comment: Also, `while(!infile.eof())` is wrong (though, that won't cause a crash - just bad logic).

Comment: @ZacHowland: The memory stuff is a low-level detail. Abusing `eof()` (and failing to check input operations) shows a high-level failure to understand an abstract I/O algorithm, which I think is much more dangerous.

Comment: Understood, though I would suggest that they are equally dangerous and bad.